# React child component does re-render when prop changes value

Tags: reactjs

As per title, my React child component does not re-render when a prop changes value. I have created an example here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/x9mzwnj04p

I tried using ComponentWillReceiveProps but it does not get called.

Comment: typo, `someValue` in child whereas it should be `someValues`, Running code https://codesandbox.io/s/vy71v445xl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the variable name wrong. The prop name you pass down to the child component is called `someValues`:

```
<ChildComponent handleClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)} someValues={someValue} />
```

But when assigning it in the child you type `someValue`, which is missing the 's':

```
const { handleClick, someValue } = this.props
```

You need to fix the name and add the 's':

```
const { handleClick, someValues } = this.props
```

And then change it in the returned JSX:

```
<span>{someValues ? 'true' : ' false'}</span><br /><br />
```

Comment: Its a simple typo, and hence should be closed

Comment: Agreed. Vote to close

Comment: Apologies, in my haste to create an example I missed that. I have put more thought into this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47517705/reach-child-does-not-update-when-state-changes